# JQ with Windows Batch - select failing

Tags: json, windows, batch-file, mule, jq

Using a Windows batch file with JQ and trying to pipe the select filter.

Example Json which is being parsed with JQ:

```
{
  "name": "test-mmc-deploy",
  "id": "local$3d2075c5-73c0-47aa-8df5-cee3a70f68c4",
  "lastModified": "Mon, 1 May 2017 13:56:15.980 AEST",
  "servers": [
    "local$520ee705-bdbb-4132-94cf-63bb213d2b46"
  ],
  "status": "DEPLOYED",
  "applications": [
    "local$f3d791bd-14d9-4491-9541-5fa04d8c3164"
  ],
  "href": "http://localhost:9090/mmc-console-3.8.2/api/deployments/local$3d2075c5-73c0-47aa-8df5-cee3a70f68c4",
  "clusterNames": [],
  "reconciled": false,
  "clusterIds": []
}
```

Normal command line JQ works with Curl and gives output as follows:

curl --basic -u admin:admin http://localhost:9090/mmc-console-3.8.2/api/deployments | jq ".data[] | select(.name==\"test-mmc-deploy\").id

*"local$3d2075c5-73c0-47aa-8df5-cee3a70f68c4"*

Trying to get the below command working in a Windows batch file is creating an escape character nightmare. Need some help please.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('echo %%app_deploy_list%% ^| jq "".data[] ^| select(.name==\"test-mmc-deploy\"^).id""') do (set app_id=%%a)
echo Application found: %app_id%
```

where %%app_deploy_list%% holds the json declared above.

The error I am getting is:
'select' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Why are you using `%%app_deploy_list%%` instead of `%app_deploy_list%`?

Comment: Hi SomethingDark, that's a mistake, I will remove it, but doesn't make a difference to the batch compiler for the select error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're escaping things unnecessarily, the command interpreter is probably inserting them literally.  That and your use of double quotes is inconsistent.  You probably cut the strings off prematurely and the filter is effectively being run as additional piped commands.

Running this directly in a command prompt works for me:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('jq ".data[] | select(.name==\"test-mmc-deploy\").id" input.json') do (echo "Application found: %a")
```

Then in a batch file, you *only* need to double the `%` for your loop variable.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('jq ".data[] | select(.name==\"test-mmc-deploy\").id" input.json') do (
    set app_id=%%a
)
echo Application found: %app_id%
```

To be able to pipe the curl response directly to jq, just escape the pipe (and nothing else).

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('curl --basic -u admin:admin http://localhost:9090/mmc-console-3.8.2/api/deployments ^| jq ".data[] | select(.name==\"test-mmc-deploy\").id"') do (
    set app_id=%%a
)
echo Application found: %app_id%
```

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that works; generally, `|`s and `)`s inside of the `in` need to be escaped.

Comment: Hi Mercado, I do not want to save a file, but use the variable which is being created as part of batch

Comment: Trying to use this ...for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('echo %app_deploy_list% ^| jq ".data[] ^| select^(.name==\"test-mmc-deploy\"^).id"') do (set app_id=%%a)
produces:jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.data[] ^| select^(.name=="test-mmc-deploy"^).id

Comment: @SomethingDark: I don't know the escaping rules by heart when it comes to the Windows command line, I'd rather pull up a bash or powershell prompt instead. But I know what you mean. But from what I remember, you only needed them for unquoted parameters. Here everything is quoted so I don't think it's really necessary. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Marking this as correct - although couldn't get around without saving a local file

Comment: @Sam: what do you mean by "saving a local file"? Having a batch script? Or by directly piping the results from curl to the jq call?

Comment: HI Mercado, wanted to directly pipe the echo variable to the jq, instead of saving to any json file. The echo variable is being populated as part of another curl with jq.

Comment: @Sam: Please, the name's Jeff. ;)  I added how you would pipe those results into jq. Basically you went a little overboard with the escaping.

Comment: Thanks JEFF! :) This works .. and yes I escaped the hell out of everything. This works confirmed. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Windows is attempting to pipe the output of `jq` into `select`, but can't find the executable `select`.

I'm unfamiliar with `curl` and `jq` but it would appear that you require a literal `|`. In the quoted-command format you are using, a literal `|` can be produced with `^^^|`